# How to Auto-Genreate the Selected Option ID in below field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

actually i want to save STORE with WAREHOUSE ID so i decided to go with select option where i select any WAREHOUSE and it will auto detect its ID and fill the input field below.

i am using axios for sending data where i already make a table in backend for storing the warehoue id and in postman i have to manually add the warehouse id. and its work fine. now i just want to add warehouse id automatically
because making a field where user have to enter manual id is stupid thing to do.

```
    const [store, setStore] = useState([]);
    const { name, area, lat, long, wh } = store;

 const onChange = e => {
   setStore({ ...store, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
 };

 const onSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const config = {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     }
   };
   axios.post("/api/store", store, config);
   setStore({
     name: "",
     area: "",
     lat: "",
     long: "",
     wh: "",
     warehouse: "" //field where i want to auto-genrate the warehouse id
   });

 };
```

```
          <select
            className="custom-select"
            name="wh"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={wh}
          >
            {warehouses.map(ware => (
              //console.log(ware.name),
              <option key={ware._id}>{ware.name}</option>
            ))},

          </select>

          <div className="form-group">

            <input
              type="text"
              disabled
              name="warehouse"
              value={ware._id} // field where i want to show the selected warehouse id 
              required
            />

        </div>

    </div>
```

please help me to findout the solution i have tried very much , visited almost all tutorial but i didnt find related to my one

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `warehouseId` state to set selected warehouse id.

```
const [ warehouseId, setWarehouseId ] = useState("")

onSubmit = e => {
  setStore({
    ...
    warehouse: warehouseId // use warehouseId state variable
  })
}

onChange = e => {
  setStore(...)
  setWarehouseId(e.target.id) // use selected option id
}

// Select options
<option key={ware._id} id={ware._id}>{ware.name}</option> // add id attribute

// Input
<input
  ...
  value={warehouseId}  // update value attribute
/>
```

Comment: sir actually i want to get the same warehouse  id which is given below in my front end when i select warehouse .   ```` {
        "_id": "5d63c113ba6e6b2078dfa4f5",
        "name": "MANGO WAREHOUSE",
        "area": "MANGO",
        "lat": "22.824780",
        "long": "86.211755",
        "__v": 0
    },````  this is my warehouse document schema